# ArcGIS Pro tool is failing. "Set LAS Class Codes Using Features"

Tags: arcgis-pro, las

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and I have a nice LAS Dataset. It came to me with the points already classified. The classifications are off, many buildings are classified as vegetation, for example.

I'm trying to use a building footprints layer to re-classify the points. For some reason the tool keeps failing. It doesn't seem to matter if my LAS Dataset is large or 1 square. It fails every time. I do get small results from it once in a while.

[image: area of town with poor classification. most buildings are classified as vegetation]

Any ideas why the tool is failing?

Comment: Are your points set to "on the ground" ? They could be set as in absolute height that might deceive you but you need to change that to set as ground...